# How to edit list title atachment on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, attachment

i use this PHP to get list my attachment title

```
<?php foreach ( $post_attachments as $post_attachment ) {echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $post_attachment->post_title);} ?>
```

but that PHP give me result like this

michael owenAndy MurrayRonaldo ...their is no space between sentence

help to to resolve like this : michael owen Andy Murray Ronaldo

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a space after or before the `echo`:

```
<?php
foreach ( $post_attachments as $post_attachment ) {
    echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $post_attachment->post_title).' '; //Add space or comma, etc.
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you so much its work @reza-mamun...do you know how to replace order A B C...we can put it C B A..